# Access user input from previous move

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am creating a simple game that takes a user input (either 0 or 1) and compares it to the computer input. Depending on the input of the user in the previous moves, the computer will take the decision to play 0 or 1.

```
select_difficulty = int(input("Choose the type of game (1: Easy; 2: Difficult): "))

moves = int(input("Enter the number of moves: "))

MS = 0
PS = 0
xi = 1234

throw00 = []
throw01 = []
throw10 = []
throw11 = []
```

The conditions are the following:

`throw00 = count of the number of times the human player chose 0 given that in the previous move he chose 0`
`throw01 = count of the number of times the human player chose 0 given in the previous move he chose 1`
`throw10 = count of the number of times the human player chose 1 given that his previous move was 0` `throw11 = count of the number of times the human player chose 1 given his/her previous bid was 1`

the following cases may occur:
If the player's last throw was 0:

`If throw10 > throw00: then the computer chooses 1`

`If throw10 < throw00: then the computer chooses 0`

`If throw10 = throw00: then the computer chooses randomly 0 or 1`

If the player's last throw was 1:

`If throw11 > throw01: then the computer chooses 1`

`If throw11 < throw01: then the computer chooses 0`

`If throw11 = throw01: then the computer chooses randomly 0 or 1.`

I've tried to this by saving the player move in a list and then access the previous move (one turn later) from that list.

```
if select_difficulty == 2:
    for turn in range(moves):
    player_move_dif = [int(n) for n in input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)).split()]`
    player_previous_move = player_move_dif[1]
```

Based on these two variables on these two variables I then append the player_move choices (0 or 1) to the respective list which is in turn used by the "computer" to choose his move

```
if player_move_dif == 0 and player_previous_move == 0:
            throw00.append(player_move_dif)
        elif player_move_dif == 0 and player_previous_move == 1:
            throw01.append(player_move_dif)
        elif player_move_dif == 1 and player_previous_move == 0:
            throw10.append(player_move_dif)
        else:
            throw11.append(player_move_dif)
        
        #define computer behavior depening on previous player move
        if player_previous_move == 0:
                if len(throw10) > len(throw00):
                    computer_move = 1
                elif len(throw10) < len(throw00):
                    computer_move = 0
                else:
                    computer_move,xi = linear_congruence(xi) 
        elif player_previous_move == 1:
                if len(throw11) > len(throw01):
                    computer_move = 1
                elif len(throw11) < len(throw01):
                    computer_move = 0
                else:
                    computer_move,xi = linear_congruence(xi)  
        else:
            computer_move,xi = linear_congruence(xi)
```

this does not work since I need the values from the player moves (as integers) for print statements to show how the game goes on

```
 if player_move_dif == computer_move:
               MS = MS + 1
               print("player = %d machine = %d - Machine wins!" % (player_move_dif, computer_move))
               print("You: %d Computer: %d" % (PS, MS))
        else:
               PS = PS + 1
               print("player = %d machine = %d - Player wins!" % (player_move_dif, computer_move))
               print("You: %d Computer: %d" % (PS, MS))
        
        print('PLAYER: ' + '*'*PS)
        print('MACHINE: ' + '*'*MS)
        
    if turn == moves and PS > MS:
        print("The game has ended, you win!")
    elif PS == MS:
        print("The game has ended, it is a draw!")
    else:
        print("the game has ended, the machine wins!")
```

this way this currently results in a TypeError %d format: a number is required, not list. I suspect I am on the wrong path how to solve this the way I'm trying now as I cannot find solution to define the variables the way I want to while simultaneously be able to access them later as needed.

Comment: Is your indenting intentional for the `if select_difficulty` block?

Comment: @ShanS: no, I edited the question to reflect the code as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides i'm not sure if the logic of the game is implemented correctly, i found some issues which led to your error.

If you want to save the player's move into a list, you have to create an empty list before the for loop, otherwise you overwrite it again and again. Also you got the problem, that there are no previous moves at the very first move, so you need a start number at first:

```
player_move_dif = [] #create an empty list out of your for-loop

for i, turn in enumerate(range(moves)): #use enumerate() to count the loops
    if i > 0: #first move has no previous one
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your move number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)).split()))
        player_previous_move = int(player_move_dif[i-1])
    else:
        player_move_dif.append(input("Choose your start number %s (0 or 1):" % (turn+1)).split()))
        continue #no action after the first move
```

Then you can access the current moves by an index of your move list. In your case the last index of your list is the last move the player did:

```
if player_move_dif == computer_move:
   MS = MS + 1
   print("player = %d machine = %d - Machine wins!" % (int(player_move_dif[-1]), computer_move)) #pick the last move from play_move_dif
   print("You: %d Computer: %d" % (PS, MS))
else:
   PS = PS + 1
   print("player = %d machine = %d - Player wins!" % (int(player_move_dif[-1]), computer_move)) #pick the last move from play_move_dif
   print("You: %d Computer: %d" % (PS, MS))
```

Comment: thanks! now I just have the issue that turn is always moves-1 which results in the game ending on the wrong turn.

Comment: For now I solved it by setting turn = 1 within the loop.

Comment: I see. You can of course also add "% (turn+1)).split()" to the input as you did before